# Uniform Roe algebras and exact groups

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group.

Q: If $l^\infty(\Gamma)\rtimes \Gamma=l^\infty(\Gamma)\rtimes_r \Gamma$ canonically, can we conclude that $\Gamma$ is an exact group?

The converse implication is well-known and if we replace $l^\infty(\Gamma)$ by $l^\infty(\Gamma)/C_0(\Gamma)$ we have indeed an affirmative answer to the question. The latter fact can be found in Section 5 of "Ghostbusting and property A" by Roe and Willett or Theorem 5.6 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01829.pdf

Comment: By "canonically isomorphic", do you mean that "the canonical map from the full to the reduced cross product is an isomorphism"?

Comment: @m07kl Yes. See Theorem 4.4.3 in Brown and Ozawa's book, C*-algebras and finite dimensional approximation properties

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes. :)

Comment: @CalebEckhardt: I don't think you can apply Theorem 4.4.3, because here you only use one $C^*$-algebra namely $l^\infty(\Gamma)$.  Please see http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3050 for a partial solution.

Comment: @m07kl Of course you're right, sorry for the ignorant comment. I have to admit that I just assumed the answer to your question was "yes" for years

Comment: The answer is affirmative and it follows from a very recent paper by Anantharaman-Delaroche see arXiv:1604.01724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See final remark of "SOME REMARKS ABOUT THE WEAK CONTAINMENT PROPERTY FOR
GROUPOIDS AND SEMIGROUPS" by Claire Anantharaman-Delaroche for an affirmative answer of the question.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01724.pdf

edit (by AlexE): the cited argument is flawed, see my comment below.

Comment: It looks like a nice argument. Why not give an outline of the argument here?

Comment: The final remark that you refer to is flawed. In fact, in the new version of the paper you don't find it anymore. Concretely, I was told by Kang Li that Cor. 2.12 in version 3 of the paper is wrong, which invalidates the final step in the final remark you mention. As far as I know, your question is currently still open.